# Strange folders name with GNU Grub Shell

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, grub

Accidentally, I delete EFI partition or some partition that I don't really know (just bcz I didnt read docs carefully and delete a random one :<). However, when I reboot my laptop, it shows GNU Grub Shell instead of Selection Page to select OS to boot.

When I try to print all the folders inside the Linux Mint partition (GPT) it showed some folders. But only one folder that I can use for commands (System Recovery) and others namely with prefix `$` (eg. `$Boot`) that I cant do anything with them. Why this happened and how to fix? Can I still boot Linux Mint using Grub Shell?

Im using Dual Boot Windows 10 and Linux Mint. Now I only can use Windows using command `exit`. Command to boot Linux Mint (ubuntu) isnt working bcz missing directories